# After an ajax post, I have problems for displaying results

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view named **Index.cshtml** with a table of users (create/edit/update functionalities).

[image]

When buttons (create/edit/update) are clicked I have a jQuery dialog for it. Next I use an ajax post like this:

- Edit >> call an action controller for editing and return a json >> update row table with javascript
- Delete >> call an action controller for deleting and return a json >> delete row table with javascript
- Create >> call an action controller for creating and redirect to Index.cshtml >> ???

For the create part, I have a problem: I would like "simply" to display my view but I am in an ajax post. I don't know how to proceed.

Here is my code (submitting data and then refreshing the view):

```
        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function (data, status) {
            $('#my-modal').modal('hide');

            if (data.operation == 'edit') {
                // Edit
                var row = $('#' + data.userid);
                row.children(':eq(0)').text(data.company);
                row.children(':eq(1)').text(data.username);
                row.children(':eq(2)').text(data.email);
                row.children(':eq(3)').text(data.firstname);
                row.children(':eq(4)').text(data.lastname);
            } else if (data.operation == 'delete') {
                // Delete
                var row = $('#' + data.userid);
                row.remove();
            } else {
                // Create
                alert(data);
                $("#userList").html(data);
            }
        })
```

As you can see, I check the data.operation which tells me if I do an 'edit' or 'delete' of (last possibility) a 'create'. For the create the problem is that my entire view (< html> < body>...) is generated and added in my #userList div. That's duplicate things.

Maybe that's not the right thing to do?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATED**

Here is my **Create** action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(UserCreateViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            this.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            return PartialView("Create", viewModel);
        }

        var userDTO = new UserDTO();
        Mapper.Map(viewModel, userDTO);
        _requestServiceClient.CreateNewUser(userDTO);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Here is my **Index** action:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index(string q, int? page)
    {
        var users = _requestServiceClient.GetUsers();
        ...
        ...
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return PartialView(userListPaged);
        else
            return View(usersListPaged);
    }
```

After relexion, in case of 'create' maybe it is better in my view to simply reload the page like this:

```
            ...
            } else if (data.operation == 'create') {
                // Create >> refresh the page
                location.reload();
            }
```

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please post your Create action, then I'm able to help.

Comment: I updated my question to show the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is not too long I would suggest to send back the complete list in every ajax request, doesn't matter if update, create or delete.

So you can remove your data operation check (your :eq(0) stuff will fail if you change the order of the columns some day) and simply put the result from the ajax request in your #userlist div.

**EDIT**

But to solve your create problem:

Just replace in the Create action this line:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

with this line:

```
return PartialView("Index", _requestServiceClient.GetUsers());
```

and it should return only the new list.

**EDIT2**

Ok, your Index.cshtml seems to have the complete layout, not just the list as I thought. So you have to do this first:

1. Move just the HTML code required to build the list in a seperate View, name it `_List.cshtml` for example
2. At the place where the HTML code was in your Index.cshtml put `@Html.Partial("_List")` in there
3. At this point your index view should look the same as before but you have your list view seperatly
4. Change my example above to not return the Index but the _List partial:
   `return PartialView("_List", _requestServiceClient.GetUsers());`

I hope that works for you.

Comment: I try it (return PartialView("Index, ....)) and the complete html is posted back (< HTML> < BODY>...). Not what I want. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I added the "EDIT2" block to my answer, please try that

Answer (score 0):

Place this code into your partial view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

This code says that you don't need a master view for this page.